What is the purple question mark square near Granny's cabin?
Near the start of Celeste 64: Fragments of the Mountain, there is a purple square with a question mark on it close to Granny's house. Standing on the block has no effect.
What is this purple question mark block for?


I don't have enough knowledge of the game to write a full answer, but check this, it's explained. It's a secret square that you activate with purple-haired Madelaine (double dash): https://itch.io/t/3473886/squareplatform-near-granny

You need to stand on the square while having a double dash to get a Strawberry. Grab the Double dash at the top of the image and go all the way around the center tower back to the secret square!

Source, here.

As pinkerman stated, you need to grab a double dash then make it back to the purple tile without dashing to get a strawberry. Below is a video showing how to do this.



